# C++: how to get input using two kind of ways,like cin and file?

Tags: c++, linux, io, cin

I have written a c++ program which can get info from a file, but it must support two ways of reading the data.

The first way is by passing the filename as a command line parameter: `./a.out a.txt`

The second one is by reading from a pipe: `cat a.txt | ./a.out`

The second way is more important and more difficult for me. How can it be done?

Here is detail about my question:

There is a class,which i defined like this:

class API_EXPORT SamReader{

```
// constructor / destructor
```

public:
    SamReader(void);
    ~SamReader(void);

```
// closes the current SAM file
bool Close(void);
// returns filename of current SAM file
const std::string GetFilename(void) const;

// return if a SAM file is open for reading
bool IsOpen(void) const;

// opens a SAM file
// *** HERE　IS MY QUESTION
bool Open(const std::string& filename);
bool Open(std::istream cin); //HERE~~~~

// retrives next available alignment
bool LoadNextAlignment(BamAlignment& alignment);
```

private:
    Internal::SamReaderPrivate * d;
};

I have got the way to input a file and get the result, But I need to add a func in this class,
make it can input from stdin...

Thanks for help, I am new guy here and I am really appreciate people who help me just now.

Comment: depending on whether there's a command line parameter, either read from `std::cin` or from the file specified by the command line parameter.

Comment: What do you mean, the more important is the second way?  For command line programs, the usual convention is to pass the name(s) of the input files as arguments to the function, and read from standard in if there are none (or if the name of the file is `"-"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read from a pipe, your program just simply need to read from stdin.  That's how pipe in shell works, if you run `a | b`, it simply passes all output on stdout of `a` to stdin of `b`.

So basically your program needs to cover 2 cases:  (1) read from a file if one is provided and (2) read from stdin otherwise.

To avoid code repetition, the easiest way is always read from stdin.  That obviously will cover (2).  To cover (1), when a file is provided as a param, use `freopen` to override stdin with that file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc > 1) {
    freopen(argv[1], "r", stdin);
  }

  string s;
  while (cin >> s) {
    cout << s << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Demonstrating how this works

```
$ g++ test.cc
$ cat content
This
is
a
test
$ ./a.out content
This
is
a
test
$ cat content | ./a.out
This
is
a
test
```

Comment: To avoid code repetition, read from an `std::istream` (or a `FILE*`, although that's generally not a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Sander De Dycker said. This is none of program's business. it depends on the shell you're using, I guess you using the classic sh.

You can write a very simple c++ program, such as:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    string s;

    while (cin >> s)
    v.push_back(s);

    for (int i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i)
    cout << v[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

then, you can type `./a.out a.txt` for using the `a.txt` as *output*, or type `cat a.txt | ./a.out` for using the `a.txt` as *input*. or you also can mix that two commands.

Comment: It should be `./a.out > a.txt`. For input, `./pgm < in.txt` is simpler IMO. Both can be mixed. (Well, the exact syntax for redirection depends on the shell you're using.. but we'll assume classic sh here.)